# How to reference a json array having key value pairs using php

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array, keyvaluepair

I've read through similar posts but still could use some help in my case...I'm having a devil of a time getting values from a json array that contains key and value pairs:

```
{"address": "4 Ficticious Ave", 
"city": "Miami", 
"country": "United States", 
"email": "jane_doe@gmail.com", 
"first_name": "Jane", 
"last_name": "Doe", 
"state": "FL", 
"zip_code": "03423", 
"response_data": 
"[{"key":"7122", "value":"37-52"},
{"key":"7123","value":"Female"},
{"key":"7124","value":"$35,000 to $50,000 USD"},
{"key":"6176","value":"Miami"},
{"key":"6177","value":"FL"},
{"key":"6179","value":"United States"}]"}
```

I've tried to get all of the values, but have been unsuccessful particularly with the response_data key|value pairs:

`// GET THE JSON DATA FROM THE $data array

```
// Identify the content as json
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

// get the contents of the JSON file
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");

//decode JSON data to PHP array
$content = json_decode($data, true);

//Fetch the details of customer
$Cust_Fname = $content['first_name'];
$Cust_Lname = $content['last_name'];
$Cust_Email = $content['email'];
$Street_Address = $content['address'];
$City = $content['city'];
$State = $content['state'];
$Country = $content['country'];
$Postal_Code = $content['zip_code'];

//also fetch the appended "array" of key/value fields...
$Response_AgeKey = $content['reponse_data'][0]['key'];
$Response_GenderKey = $content['reponse_data'][1]['key'];
$Response_IncomeKey = $content['reponse_data'][2]['key'];
$Response_CityKey = $content['reponse_data'][3]['key'];
$Response_StateKey = $content['reponse_data'][4]['key'];
$Response_CountryKey = $content['reponse_data'][5]['key'];
$Response_Age = $content['reponse_data'][0]['value'];
$Response_Gender = $content['reponse_data'][1]['value'];
$Response_Income = $content['reponse_data'][2]['value'];
$Response_City = $content['reponse_data'][3]['value'];
$Response_State = $content['reponse_data'][4]['value'];
$Response_Country = $content['reponse_data'][5]['value']
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone said the "response_data" is not valid JSON. There is a pair of extra double quotes enclosing the array.But i think if it is a response  and not a manually typed json it will be better to automatically  normalize the received string before decode it with Json_decode mainly by Removing the enclosing double .You can use the code below to achieve it:

```
<?php
 // Identify the content as json
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

// get the contents of the JSON file
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");

//normalize the json in order to be properly decoded

$start=strpos($data,':',strpos($data,'response_data'));
$get=substr($data,$start+1,strrpos($data,'"')-$start);
$data=str_replace($get,trim(trim($get),'"'),$data);

//decode JSON data to PHP array
$content = json_decode($data, true);

//Fetch the details of customer

$Cust_Fname = $content['first_name'];
$Cust_Lname = $content['last_name'];
$Cust_Email = $content['email'];
$Street_Address = $content['address'];
$City = $content['city'];
$State = $content['state'];
$Country = $content['country'];
$Postal_Code = $content['zip_code'];

//also fetch the appended "array" of key/value fields...
$Response_AgeKey = $content['reponse_data'][0]['key'];
$Response_GenderKey = $content['reponse_data'][1]['key'];
$Response_IncomeKey = $content['reponse_data'][2]['key'];
$Response_CityKey = $content['reponse_data'][3]['key'];
$Response_StateKey = $content['reponse_data'][4]['key'];
$Response_CountryKey = $content['reponse_data'][5]['key'];
$Response_Age = $content['reponse_data'][0]['value'];
$Response_Gender = $content['reponse_data'][1]['value'];
$Response_Income = $content['reponse_data'][2]['value'];
$Response_City = $content['reponse_data'][3]['value'];
$Response_State = $content['reponse_data'][4]['value'];
$Response_Country = $content['reponse_data'][5]['value']

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it always helps to have an extra pair of eyes!  Ok, so the code runs without error and the data gets inserted as a new record in MySQL [code not provided].  Strange thing is that none of the data from the response_data key value pairs shows up...all of those columns are blank.  Guess I gotta play around with that retrieval syntax.  Thanks much...I am much further along now.

Answer (score 1):

the `"response_data"` is not valid JSON. There is a pair of extra double quotes enclosing the array. Remove the enclosing double quotes then it should work.

```
{
  "address": "4 Ficticious Ave",
  "city": "Miami",
  "country": "United States",
  "email": "jane_doe@gmail.com",
  "first_name": "Jane",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "state": "FL",
  "zip_code": "03423",
  "response_data": [
    {
      "key": "7122",
      "value": "37-52"
    },
    {
      "key": "7123",
      "value": "Female"
    },
    {
      "key": "7124",
      "value": "$35,000 to $50,000 USD"
    },
    {
      "key": "6176",
      "value": "Miami"
    },
    {
      "key": "6177",
      "value": "FL"
    },
    {
      "key": "6179",
      "value": "United States"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this....it helped for me to have the removal code as provided by @Elementary.